# Phonegap facebook api no angularJS

Tags: angularjs, apache-cordova, plugin

Segundo este projeto https://github.com/jeduan/cordova-plugin-facebook4, eu instalei via git-shell, este plugin no meu phonegap, fui até a pasta root e executei o shell. Bom Pelo menos, neste tutorial, não tinha nada mais explicando, mas quando chamo `facebookConnectPlugin` ele está `undefined`. Eu preciso fazer mais alguma coisa pra poder usar este plugin?
Ele criou uma pasta plugins, no mesmo diretorio onde está a pasta www, e dentro desta pasta plugin, ele criou a pasta do facebook-connect.

Comment: Michel, você está fazendo muitas perguntas relacionadas apenas de modo diferente. Já é a 3ª questão com a mesma base. Faça apenas uma pergunta sobre o problema e aguarde a resposta.

Comment: Me desculpe, eu rodei e rodei, até entender que o phonegap não permite usar as proprias apis do facebook porque ele tem a dele, então fui atrás de saber como que era e achei. Só que no tutorial, eles só falam pra instalar via npm, eu instalo, mas quando chamo a função está indefinida.